# Limit exponent only to specific powers

Tags: c#, string-formatting

In our program we have values around millions to milliards which need to be displayed. Due to user requirements, the users want to see only exponent values which are dividable by 3. means the values to be displayed shall be like

- 1e0
- 10e0
- 100e0
- 1e3
- 10e3
- 100e3
- 1e6

and so on. I want to change exponent where thousands are encountered, to simplify the user the way to distinguish kilobits, megabits, gigabits.

Is it possible to get this effect with a format string?

Comment: Why not format it as SI Units? You know... Mega, Giga, Tera, Peta... Anyway I dunno anything to do that specifically, I'd use a logarithm and write my own. I have an SI Unit implementation if interested. I would at least use like 5 x 10^3 or some human format. That e nonsense is just old calculator garbage

Comment: Your best bet would to write a ToString() extension method for your type.

Comment: I also proposed my boss to format as Mega, Giga, etc, but most of our users are the old school electrotechnics guys, who explicitly wish the e notation. However, the giga, etc would be there as optional format, thats a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from Servy was the starting point, but it still had some bugs, not working for negative or very small values. I expanded it like this

```
        double exponent = Math.Log10(Math.Abs(val));

        var negcompensator = 0;
        if (exponent < 0)
        {
            negcompensator = -1;
        }
        int displayExponent = (int)(Math.Truncate((exponent + negcompensator) / 3)) * 3;

        if (displayExponent==0 || double.IsInfinity(exponent))
        {
            return val.ToString("###0.##");
        }
        else
        {
            var displayValue = (val / Math.Pow(10, displayExponent));
            return string.Format("{0}e{1}", displayValue, displayExponent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
int val = 123456789;
var order = (int)Math.Log10(val);
var auxOrder = order/3;
var charToShow = val.ToString().Length - (auxOrder *3);
var result = val.ToString().Substring(0, charToShow )+"e"+(auxOrder *3);
```

There are better names for the variables like mantissa e exponent, but it will do the trick

Answer (score -2):

I dislike solutions like this that involve string manipulation, so I calculated both portions mathematically here.

```
public static string MyFormat(int value)
{
    double exponent = Math.Log10(value);
    int displayExponent = (int)(exponent / 3);

    int displayValue = (int)(value / Math.Pow(exponent, 10));
    return string.Format("{0}e{1}", displayValue, displayExponent);
}
```